# MySql optimize group by when group by uses a function

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table hardBrake with the following schema :

```
      -------------------- --------------------
     | Column Name        |  Type              |
      -------------------- --------------------
     |  id                | CHAR(36) primary   |
      -------------------- --------------------
     |  vehicleId         | CHAR(36)           |
      -------------------- --------------------
     |  address           | VARCHAR(50)        |
      -------------------- --------------------
     |  time              | TIMESTAMP          |
      -------------------- --------------------
```

Now when I am running my query and trying to group it using time column with day() function and used EXPLAIN EXTENDED on the select query it shows using temporary and filesort along with using where and using index.

I am using time + vehicleId column as index and my select query is :

```
select count(1),CONVERT_TZ(time,'+00:00', :offset) as dateOfIncident 
from hardBrake 
where vehicleId in (vehicleIds) 
  and time between NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY and NOW() 
group by day(dateOfIncident ) 
order by time DESC;
```

offset field and vehicleId field I am passing from my java code that is the time zone difference between users time zone and db time zone that is in GMT and vehicleIds of customer respectively.

Is it possible to remove temporary and filesort for a query that uses group by on a function???

A sneak peak of my problem :

I want to get hardBrake incident for a customer date wise in his time zone. As an alternative can I do any changes in java side without having to go for time zone in mysql.

Comment: Why do you GROUP BY `dateofincident` instead of `time`?

Comment: If I will group by time then I will get results group by db time zone i.e. GMT but I want to group them on the basis of users time zone which offset I am passing from my code.

Comment: I see - so there's a chance that the local time and the users time could overlap different days.

Comment: Yeah it could but still we have to mostly handle users with PST timezone and there may be users with other time zone also.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this query cannot avoid the temporary table.
Refer to this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html

> The most important preconditions for using indexes for GROUP BY are that all GROUP BY columns reference attributes from the same index, and that the index stores its keys in order .....

Since the query is using a function `CONVERT_TZ(time,'+00:00', :offset)` to obtain GROUP BY values, MySql cannot retrieve these values from the index, it must calculate them "on the fly" using the function, and must store them in the temporary table.

---

The same problem is with the filesort,
read this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE clause. These cases include the following: 
>   ..........
>   ..........
>   - You have different ORDER BY and GROUP BY expressions.

The query has different GROUP BY and ORDER BY expressions:

```
group by day(dateOfIncident ) 
order by time DESC;
```

therefore MySql cannot use the index, and must use the filesort.

Comment: Even removing order by does not help here, I think use of day function for grouping is causing the problem.